# Textures Changing when selected

Tags: texturing, uv

So I'm making a wood shed with wood textures and stuff.

For whatever reason, when I select certain objects, their texture changes.

Before I select them

[image: not selected]

After I select them

[image]

Now it is a *slight* difference, but it should not be doing that.

Anyone know what the heck is happening?

Comment: Hey, this is interesting :). Would you mind [sharing the file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Oh I do have the finished file, but I just deleted those objects and re-made them to solve the issue :/  here is the file anyway.                       
       https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c5cdI4Kr5V6kAJajZ9PSBLFM8KJY0wui